# Handling $http promises in your service or controller?

Tags: angularjs

I find my controller gets stuffed with promise functions and my service has only got a few lines,

is good practice to handle the promise in the service?

As shown below I this is using $http.post and I've got a few more $http.get in my service as well.

```
// $http.post
    logService.insertLog($scope.newLog)
        .then(onInsertSuccess)
        .catch(onError);
// $http.get
    logService.getPriority()
        .then(onPrioritySuccess)
        .catch(onError);

var onPrioritySuccess = function (response) {
    $scope.priority = response.data;
};
```

would it be better to have something like this?

```
// store the response in the scope directly?
$scope.priority = logService.getPriority();
```

Answer (score 0):

anyway since getPriority eventually is a $http request you will have to return a promise so your controller code will look similar.

what you wrote on the top seems fine.